# How do I get a Win7 app to communicate with a website?

Tags: c++

I have sought in vain for a book entitled "Website Communication for Dummies".  Can anyone suggest some good reading material / tutorial for me to consult?

Here is where I am at:  I have a 32-bit Windows app I have written in C++ using Visual Studio 2010 C++ Express.  The app facilitates User selection of an URL in text format == i.e., www.maps.google.com -- and then creates a socket and connects it, etc.  The problem is that I can use the "send" command w/o error, but I have no idea what content to send in the 2nd argument, which is a const char[].

I've tried simple commands like "dump" and "refresh" for various websites, but the recv() function merely returns 0 (bytes received) after a long delay.

Thanks for attending to this.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what sort of data goes back and forth between web server and a client, look at the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) (or start with a [tutoral](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/)).

When you have the understanding of the protocol and played with raw sockets, look for C or C++ implementations. libcurl would be one such. I also think Windows has build-in support for HTTP clients in Windows SDK.

Comment: Windows' wininet lib is a native high-level lib for http and ftp communication. I believe there are apis that do a whole request in a single call.

Comment: Not really, but MSDN has fairly complete examples down to the hourglass.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to send something like

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

to get a proper http response. However most sites will disregard requests that don't include certain HTTP headers (e.g. Host). I would advise looking up http client libraries in C++ to do some of the grunt work for you, writing your own http request building code is very much reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

First use `send`( `GET / HTTP/1.1..` )  to the webserver to make a request, and after that use `recv(Socket,buffer..)` to download the website HTML code into a buffer.

```
send(Socket,"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"),0);
```

Winsock code:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;
int main (){
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    SOCKET Socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    struct hostent *host;
    host = gethostbyname("www.google.com");
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port=htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
    cout << "Connecting...\n";
    if(connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
        cout << "Could not connect";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Connected.\n";
    send(Socket,"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"),0);
    char buffer[10000];
    int nDataLength;
    while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket,buffer,10000,0)) > 0){        
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
            cout << buffer[i];
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    closesocket(Socket);
        WSACleanup();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```